# Remove first occurrence of underscore in a string

Tags: r

I have a character string of names which look like

```
"_6302_I-PAL_SPSY_000237_001"
```

I need to remove the first occurred underscore, so that it will be as

```
"6302_I-PAL_SPSY_000237_001"
```

I aware of `gsub` but it removes all of underscores. Thank you for any suggestions.

Comment: Do you want to remove the *first occurrence* of an underscore or remove it if the *first character is* an underscore?

Answer (score 4):

We can use `sub` with pattern as `_` and replacement as blanks (`""`).  This will remove the first occurrence of '_'.

```
sub("_", "", str1)
#[1] "6302_I-PAL_SPSY_000237_001"
```

NOTE: This will remove the `first` occurence of `_` and it will not limit based on the position i.e. at the `start` of the string.

For example, suppose we have string

```
str2 <- "6302_I-PAL_SPSY_000237_001"
sub("_", "", str2)
#[1] "6302I-PAL_SPSY_000237_001"
```

---

As the example have `_` in the beginning, another option is `substring`

```
substring(str1, 2)
#[1] "6302_I-PAL_SPSY_000237_001"
```

#### data

```
str1 <- "_6302_I-PAL_SPSY_000237_001"
```

Answer (score 4):

gsub function do the same, to remove starting of the string symbol ^ used

```
    x <- "_6302_I-PAL_SPSY_000237_001"

    x <- gsub("^\\_","",x)

    [1] "6302_I-PAL_SPSY_000237_001"
```

Comment: Why do you use "\\". Seems that `gsub("^_","",x)` is enough.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done with base R's `trimws()` too

```
string1<-"_6302_I-PAL_SPSY_000237_001"

trimws(string1, which='left', whitespace = '_')

[1] "6302_I-PAL_SPSY_000237_001"
```

In case we have multiple words with leading underscores, we may have to include a word boundary (`\\b`) in our regex, and use either gsub or `stringr::string_remove`:

```
string2<-paste(string1, string1)

string2
[1] "_6302_I-PAL_SPSY_000237_001 _6302_I-PAL_SPSY_000237_001"

library(stringr)

str_remove_all(string2, "\\b_")
> str_remove_all(string2, "\\b_")

[1] "6302_I-PAL_SPSY_000237_001 6302_I-PAL_SPSY_000237_001"
```